# How to get background color of CPropertyPage?

Tags: mfc

If I try below code I am able to get background color of `CDialog`, likewise how to get background color of `CPropertyPage`.

```
CDC* pDC=GetDC();
LOGBRUSH LogBrush;

HBRUSH hBrush = (HBRUSH) SendMessage(WM_CTLCOLORDLG,(WPARAM) pDC->m_hDC,
(LPARAM) m_hWnd);
::GetObject(hBrush,sizeof(LOGBRUSH),&LogBrush);
```

Comment: Call [GetClassName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassnamew) to retrieve the target window's window class name. With that, call [GetClassInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassinfow) to retrieve its [WNDCLASS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassw). You can extract the color from its `hbrBackground` member like you did above. Note that this doesn't retrieve the actual color used by the control, in case it uses custom rendering of its background.

Comment: @IInspectable, for both CPropertySheet and CDialog I am getting class name as #32770 and the hbrBackground as 0.

Comment: This help? http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?425802-CPropertySheet-Background-Color

Comment: @Andrew, I tried your solution. For dialog your solution is fine whereas for propertysheet it returns dialog's default color which is RGB(240,240,240) but the propertysheet is displayed with white background.

Comment: Background color for property page is same as window's background (default white). Except Windows XP used to have something stupid with gradient color. Don't bother for XP compatibility in that respect.

Comment: You should use `CMFCPropertyPage` and `CMFCPropertySheet` instead.